# How can I avoid that Word does a "Different First Page" in footers and headers for new sections?

Tags: microsoft-word

I never want to insert a "*Different First Page*" except for section 1. But since all sections are linked, each new section is getting the "*Different First Page*" checkbox selected first. I would expect that *Link to Previous* takes the settings from previous which also includes deselected "*Different First Page*" in my case. This seems to be not the case. It appears to take the settings from the first section where I have it checked.

How can I change this behaviour, or insert a new section without "*Different First Page*" checked?

Answer (score 0):

Put this macro in Normal.dotm or another place you keep macros.  Assign it to a QAT button or hotkey.  (See [here](http://gregmaxey.mvps.org/word_tip_pages/installing_employing_macros.html) for details on how to do those things.)  Enjoy!

```
Sub BreakSectionNewHeaders()
    Selection.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
    Selection.InsertBreak Type:=wdSectionBreakNextPage
    Selection.Sections(1).PageSetup.DifferentFirstPageHeaderFooter = False
    Selection.Sections(1).Headers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).LinkToPrevious = False
    Selection.Sections(1).Footers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).LinkToPrevious = False
End Sub 'BreakSectionNewHeaders
```

(Word 2013 answer - may work in other versions)